# continous fadein and fadeout of background images using jquery

Tags: jquery

the code below continuously change the background image of div. please how do i cause if to fade in and fade out instead of just changing?

```
var imageFile = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg", "4.jpg"];
   var currentIndex = 0;
   setInterval(function () {
     if (currentIndex == imageFile.length) {
        currentIndex = 0;
     }
     $("#custom_body").css('background-image', 'url("images/' + imageFile[currentIndex++] + '")');
   }, 3000);
```

how do i do this please?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var seconds = 3000;
    var step = 0;
    var limit = 3;

    $("#custom_body").addClass("image-" + step).fadeIn(700);

    setInterval(function () {
        $("#custom_body").fadeOut(700, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("image-" + step);
            step = (step > limit) ? 0 : step + 1;
            $("#custom_body").addClass("image-" + step).fadeIn(700);
        });
    }, seconds);
});
```

Comment: if fades out the entire div not only the bg image

Comment: Ok then you can have two divs. 1) #custom_body 2) #img_container. Put #img_container within #custom_body. Give appropriate height and width to  #img_container. and then in above code replace  #custom_body with #img_container. Hope it will work.